Why does an HLS video stream change resolution mid stream when played through the Video.js player? Can the resolution be fixed with the player?
We recently moved to AWS to stream on-demand videos. Our products use the Video.js player in a REACT environment for a browser run-time environment (Chrome, Firefox, and Edge). The stream suddenly changes resolution mid-stream, giving the user an odd experience of the video sizing up and down. We know HLS encodes to various bit rates and resolution sizes by design. We expected Video.js would play back at the set resolution height and width and stretch any smaller resolution video chunks/segments to fit.
I'm not the developer. I'm trying to help them, so I don't know the Video.js and REACT that well. Has anyone had this problem with Video.js and do you know of a fix?
Thank you.
We used to stream from Azure and had no problems. Forced to move to AWS. We first tried using DASH but it would freeze the video sporadically and not recover.
Videojs settings are as follows:

fluid = false
aspectRatio = left undefined
height = 520px
width = 1366px

No other parameters in the video.js and react guidelines seem to be related.
https://videojs.com/guides/options/#height

We notice our AWS encoded videos have a size that is not 16:9 ratio. The theory is this might cause video.js an issue during playback. We'll be re-encoding to see if that fixes the issue with HLS.  It may even fix the DASH freeze issue as well.


We expected Video.js would play back at the set resolution height and width and stretch any smaller resolution video chunks/segments to fit.

Well, no, that expectation is not reality.  By default, the video element will be the size of the video, regardless of the source of that video.
Though, the solution is simple.  Just adjust your CSS for your video element to fit whatever size you want it to be.

We notice our AWS encoded videos have a size that is not 16:9 ratio. The theory is this might cause video.js an issue during playback.

No.  Video.js doesn't care what the size of your videos are.
